# AccessDeniedException for Kafka 3 default state.dir

Tags: java, apache-kafka, windows-10

The following error would appear every 5 seconds when we have Kafka running on Windows 10.

> Failed to write offset checkpoint file to C:/tmp/kafka-streams/user/global/.checkpoint for global stores: {}. This may occur if OS cleaned the state.dir in case when it is located in the (default) ${java.io.tmpdir}/kafka-streams directory. Changing the location of state.dir may resolve the problem.
>
> java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:/tmp/kafka-streams/user/global

Here is our Gradle. At the time of writing, this will import the 3.0 version by default.

```
api 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams'
api 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients'
```

I have checked the folder permissions and it seems be to read-only for the `kafka-streams` subfolders. Even if I change that, it'd go back to read-only.

Environment

```
JDK 17.0.2
Kafka 3.0
Windows 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warnings disappeared immediately when I bumped the Kafka version to `3.1.0`. I couldn't figure out what the cause was.

```
api 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams:3.1.0'
api 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.1.0'
```

Comment: I think you'll still get this exception with any version. Kafka is not meant to be ran against a Windows filesystem; it depends on Unix permissions